# end to end delay in Veins

Tags: c++, simulation, omnet++

I want to calculate end-to-end delay in Veins example scenario.

I have already read old mails that are related to this topic but they don't provide a real solution for the problem.

I used `getCreationTime()` and `simTime()` functions. The resulting delay is about  `1.70*10^-4`.

This delay doesn't make sense for me. It is supposed to be more. I need some help at this point. I take the creation time of `macPkt` by using `mackPkt->creationTime()` function and i extract `simTime()` from it for calculating end-to-end delay. However, it doesn't make sense.

I guess `macPkt` is not the packet created by transmitter. I need the creation time of the packet at the transmitter side. Can anyone help me? The calculating end to end delay is a problem of many users. I hope this Question help many users.

Comment: You should add some code to show your problem more in detail. Hard to read anything out of this block.

Answer (score 0):

Delays in this order of magnitude are to be expected for one-hop transmissions. See also the discussion at [Computing End-To-End Delay in Veins](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57258444/4707703) for a more detailed breakdown.

If you're talking end-to-end delay over multiple hops, note that packet creation time might note be a reliable indicator. Here, you can use the ‘timestamp‘ field of a ‘WaveShortMessage‘ to store the creation time, then use this field at the receiver to calculate the delay. If you use your own messages, just add a field of your own.

Comment: Dear Sommer, thank you for your support. I have studied modules but I couldnt find the exact function that create  a ready-to-send WSM packet. I added 'wsm->setTimestamp(simTime());' after sendWSM(wsm) command in TraCIDemo11p and TraCIDemoRSU11p module. Also, I couldnt find the exact location for receiving WSM. Where WSM is received?

Comment: If you execute the Veins tutorial, you should be able to see how nodes react to messages. Just find the line in the tutorial application that adds a colored circle. It is where nodes process received messages.

Answer (score 0):

I think following code can help you for end to end delay, you should change 
it base on `TraciDemo11p`

```
class Sink : public cSimpleModule
{
protected:
cStdDev eedStats;
virtual void initialize();
virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg);
virtual void finish();
};
Define_Module(Sink);
void Sink::initialize()
{
eedStats.setName("End-to-End Delay");
}
void Sink::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
simtime_t eed = simTime() - msg->getCreationTime();
eedStats.collect(eed);
delete msg;
}
void Sink::finish()
{
recordScalar("Simulation duration", simTime());
eedStats.record();
}
```

I think `OnWSM()` method in the `TraciDemo11p` is suitable place for receiving WSM.