# Custom Messages with Veins(oment++, sumo, veins traffic simulation)

Tags: simulation, simulator, omnet++

I am using latest version of veins. I have been playing it with for a while and understand the basics now. I followed tictoc tutorial for omentpp, but I still couldn't figure out how to solve the following probelm:

I want Vehicles and RSU to send messages to each other. I want these messages to be sent in all the four catagories. When a message is received I want to measure the time it took to travel from source to destination.

By default, veins, can send data, and based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32044168/end-to-end-delay-in-veins) post, I know that I have to change someparts in TraCIDemo11p, but I couldn't figure out what. It would be great if someone could provide an answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "all the four categories"?

Comment: In 802.11p there are four different access categories for data traffic. Any application can choose which category to use. The priority differes on each of these categories.

Comment: I don't think I understand what your question is. Could you rephrase it?

Comment: @ChristophSommer I figured the problem. I wanted each vehicle to send messages with different priorities during the same run time simulation.(Access Category = Priority?). The way I implemented this was, whenever I wanted to send a message, I would choose a random priority(Access Category) from 0-3 and assign it to the packet.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Feel free to answer your own question. StackOverflow is all about collecting good answers to (good) questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question. I modified `BaseWaveAppLayer.cc` to accomplish my goal(though it is not right way to do it. The right way would be to extend this class and make your changes in that class. But since I just wanted to make changes quickly I chose this quicker way). I modified the method for sending beacons. Since beacons will be scheduled to be sent based on the time that the user can specify in .ini file. Now every time a beacon is scheduled to be sent, I randomly generate a priority from the range [0-4) and assign it to the packet. In this way I get to send beacons with different priorities over the network.

Also as I had a requirement of sending each packet in a different rate. To achieve this I implemented the random generation function in such a way that certain numbers of the range gets generated more than others. It's sorta biased. So as an example, in .ini file I would specify that priorities 0-2 should be sent at rate of 0.2 while priority 4 should be sent at rate of 0.4(it can interpreted as the sending rate for each priority). The random generation function would then generate 4 twice more than any other number, while numbers 0,1,2 would get generated the same number of times.