# Computing End-To-End Delay in Veins

Tags: omnet++, veins

I have read a bunch of posts on SO regarding the computation of end-to-end delay in Veins, but have not found an answer to be fulfilling in explaining why the delay is seemingly too low.

I am using:

- Veins 4.7
- Sumo 0.32.0
- Omnetpp 5.3

Channel switching is turned off.

I have the following code, sending a message from the transmitting node:

```
if(sendMessage) {
  WaveShortMessage* wsm = new WaveShortMessage();
  sendDown(wsm);
}
```

The receiving node computes the delay using the wsm creation time, but I have also tried setting the timestamp on the transmitting side. The result is the same.

```
simtime_t delay = simTime() - wsm -> getCreationTime();
delayVector.record(delay);
```

The sample output for the delay vector is as follows:

Item#   Event#  Time             Value
0       165     14.400239402394  2.39402394E-4
1       186     14.500240403299  2.40403299E-4
2       207     14.600241404069  2.41404069E-4
3       228     14.700242404729  2.42404729E-4

Which means that the end-to-end delay (from creation to reception) is equivalent to roughly a quarter of a millisecond, which seems to be quite low - and a fair bit below what is typically reported in the literature. This seems to be consistent with what other people have reported as being an issue (e.g. [end to end delay in Veins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32044168/end-to-end-delay-in-veins))

Am I missing something in this computation? I have tried adding load on the network by adding a high number of vehicular nodes (21 nodes within a 1000x50 sandbox on a straight highway, with an average speed of 50 km/h), but the result seems to be the same. The difference is negligible. I have read several research papers that suggest that end-to-end delay should increase dramatically in high vehicular densities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This end-to-end delay is to be expected. If your application's simulation model does not explicitly model processing delay (e.g., by an application running on a slow general purpose computer), all you would expect to delay a frame is propagation delay (lightspeed, so negligible here) and queueing delay on the MAC (time from inserting frame into TX queue until transmission finishes).

To give an example, for a 2400 bit frame sent at 6 Mbit/s this delay is roughly 0.45 ms. You are likely using slightly shorter frames, so your values appear to be reasonable.

For background information, see [F. Klingler, F. Dressler, C. Sommer: "The Impact of Head of Line Blocking in Highly Dynamic WLANs"](http://www.ccs-labs.org/bib/klingler2018impact/) (DOI [10.1109/TVT.2018.2837157](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TVT.2018.2837157)), which also includes a comparison of theory vs. Veins vs. real measurements.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the reply. So in trying to decipher some of the existing literature on end-to-end delay where the reported figures are typically higher (e.g. https://jwcn-eurasipjournals.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/1687-1499-2014-89), I suppose these would be under high loads and corresponding high queueing delays.

Comment: Note that the authors of the paper you cited do not investigate queueing delay. Rather, they report the number of milliseconds that elapse between two successfully received packets. Naturally, this delay is proportional to the packets loss rate -- as also evidenced by the 1:1 correspondence of plots for delay and PDR reported in Figures 3 and 5. Note further that packet loss rates in this study are negatively influenced by mismatched parameter choice (notably only for the 11p part): no retries as well as very high and non-adaptive transmit power and rate with fully radio-transparent buildings.

Comment: I see - this wasn't immediately obvious to me. Thank you so much for clarifying!