# Time to Sucessfull Transmission of a Frame in 802.11p MAC Layer - Veins

Tags: veins

I am looking for some model or equation that, given the size of a frame, provide the time (channel access duration) needed to ensure a successfull transmission of this frame in 802.11p in Veins Framework.

My idea is use this value to guarantee channel access for some nodes in the network, with a non-zero probability of successfull transmission.

I've found the equation bellow in the class [Mac1609_5.cc](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/master/src/veins/modules/mac/ieee80211p/Mac1609_4.cc)

```
simtime_t sendingDuration = RADIODELAY_11P + phy11p->getFrameDuration(mac->getBitLength(), usedMcs);
```

My question is, this is only the time that I need to take into account? There is some another behavior in veins that affects the time to transmit one frame?

Cheers.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57269871/4707703 for a comment to a very similar question. The paper linked there has a detailed breakdown of involved delays, depending on MAC state and channel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Computing End-To-End Delay in Veins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57258444/computing-end-to-end-delay-in-veins)

Comment: Hi Sommer, thank you for you answer. 
I believe I am was not clear in my question. I am trying to find the minimum expected duration to guarantee a sucessfull transmission of node in a 802.11p network. This duration should consider, for example: delay for processing the packet header, and another MAC layer related delays in the process of send one packet. To be clear I want find this duration to define time of channel access per node. Propagation delay and other associated delays does not matter for this characterization. I would like to find these models in veins, if it exist.

Thank you.

Comment: I don’t think I quite understand. Could you contrast what you want to know vs. what is explained in the cited paper? Maybe this will give me a clearer picture.

Comment: For now I will spend some time understanding the paper.

But being direct, I would like to know how in veins could I for example divide the channel access, either CCH duration or SCH duration (which is actually 50 ms) giving some parts of this duration for nodes disputing channel access. But I need to model the behavior of the channel to define how to perform this. This solution will be centralized at a first time.

Comment: Glad to hear it!